# How to sort multiple named ranges based on one column?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to sort multiple named ranges in one excel sheet which already named by Data1, Data2,...

In each named range, there is a cell that will be used for sorting. My problem is I want all the data in the named range to move accordingly to the sorted cell.

Based on the picture, if column A is sorted, the data in the right side also move upward.

[image: Example of my files]

Comment: I tried this one, but this one is used to sort the data in each of the name range

<code>Sub sortingdata()


    Dim nRange As name
    For Each nRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If UCase(nRange.name) Like ("TEST*") Then
            Range(nRange.name).Sort Key1:=Range(nRange.name).Cells(2, 3), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        End If
    Next nRange
End Sub
<code>

Comment: You can also edit your question to add the code there.

Comment: why would you ever want to do such a thing??? Maybe the answer is "think again avout those named ranges things"

Comment: may be you add some examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios

Comment: because user will insert a set of data same as the image above @Pierre

Comment: @mfo_28 : how does it imply you should use named ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want to sort on is a repeated string in several rows, such as Column A, Rows 24-50 all contain "file1" then you can use the following code to select all rows that contain that string in the specified column. From there you can apply your sort.

```
    Private Sub Test1()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim Fitem As String 
    Dim FEndRange As Long
    Dim FStartRange As Long

'Search for the name of the header you want to base your range off of...

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireRow
    Set c = .Find("HEADER", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(c.Address).EntireColumn
    Set d = .Find("file1", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(d.Row, c.Column)
    Fitem = c.Value
    End With

    If (c.EntireColumn.Find(what:=Fitem, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Cells(2, c.Column)).Row)  0 Then
    FStartRange = c.EntireColumn.Find(what:=Fitem, After:=Cells(1, c.Column)).Row
    FEndRange = c.EntireColumn.Find(what:=Fitem, After:=Cells(1, c.Column), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(FStartRange, d.Column).Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(FStartRange, d.Column), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(FEndRange, d.Column)).EntireRow.Select

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=c, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort

'place your sort criteria here

    End With
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I want to sort the named ranges. can we lock the data to the cell that I want to sort, so that it will move together? Please refer to the image above, I just attached

Comment: This might be easier with offset given your data. I would start by locating the row values of Data1 and Data2, and then set a row range of Data2 to be Data2 through (Data1-Data2)-2 to account for the blank space. For Data2 use find the last row or for your reference or if you have a Data3, Data4, etc. then make a loop function to calculate each iteration of "Data[n]". Then you can offset the columns by 4 as well. That way the sort will be in reference to the Data1 and Data2 labels.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new info from your picture and comments the following code should get you where you need to be.

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Test()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Activate
    y = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "Data*")
    s = 1

    For x = 1 To y
    s = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Data*", after:=Range("A" & s)).Row

    If x = y Then
    t = lastrow + 2
    Else
    t = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="Data*", after:=Range("A" & s)).Row
    End If

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(s, 5), ws.Cells(t - 2, 17)).Select

'Add sort criteria here

    Next x

    End Sub
```

The letters I use are arbitrary and can be changed to anything.